# Print names and nrow of a list of dataframes in a loop in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, loops, for-loop

I loop with a list of dataframes and like to show their names and number of rows:

```
library(tidyverse)

data(Affairs, BankWages)
df_list <- list(Affairs, BankWages)
names(df_list) <- c("Affairs", "BankWages")
names(df_list[1]) # one works

for (i in df_list){
  #print(names(df_list[i])) # loop does not work 
  print(i %>% nrow())
}
```

Such that it repeats

```
Dataframe Affairs contains 601 observations
Dataframe BankWages contains 474 observations
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are loading `tidyverse`, you can use `lst` to create a named list, and `map2_vec` + `glue` to create the sentences:

```r
lst(mtcars, cars) %>% 
  map2_vec(names(.), ~ glue::glue("Dataframe {.y} contains {nrow(.x)} observations"))
```

output

```r
Dataframe mtcars contains 32 observations
Dataframe cars contains 50 observations
```

---

Note that you need `purrr 1.0.0` for `map2_vec`.

Comment: Looks good, I'm not able to install 1.0.0 of `purrr`. Working on it.

Comment: Works. How can I extend this approach, say to "distinct observations"? Does not work: 

lst(mtcars, mtcars*2) %>% 
  distinct(cyl) %>% 
  map2_vec ....

Comment: Distinct observation of which column? the same over the multiple dfs?

Comment: Yes, assume some columns are different. But I'd like to compare a common column variable in each dataframe.

Comment: Then include it in your `map2_vec` call. Everything you do at the level of the dataframe (not the list of datafrmaes) should be done inside `map`.